# I'm trying to scan data condiionally, as long as it's not the end of the file in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements, eof, scanf

I am trying to read lines from a text file written in a certain format and want to keep reading as long as it's not the end of the file. However, the program stops right when it gets to this loop. Is this how I would test for EOF without advancing the fscanf?

```
    while (getchar() != EOF){       //as long as it's not end of file, keep scanning in the following format.
    fscanf(inputFile, "%li*%ll**%^[,]***%^[,]**%^[,]*%i***%^[,]*", &list[i].term, &list[i].sID, &list[i].lastName, &list[i].firstName,
        &list[i].subject, &list[i].catalog, &list[i].section);
    i++;                        //increment array index counter
}
```

Comment: You should be checking the return status from `fscanf()` (and it should be `if (fscanf(inputFile, "…", …) != 7) { …EOF or format error…; break; }` or (better) `while fscanf(inputFile, "…", …) == 7) i++;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getchar()` will read from `stdin`, but your `fscanf(inputFile, ...);` will read from `inputFile`, you cannot use `getchar()` to check whether you have reached the end of `inputFile`.

You could use `while (fscanf(inputFile, ...) == 7) {` to achieve your goal in this case.

From `fscanf(3)`:

> These  functions  return  the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful  conversion  or  a matching  failure  occurs.  EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

Comment: +1 but it should use `while (fscanf(...) == 7)` (so that you can spot when there is a format error so that only 4 of 7 fields are converted correctly).

Comment: thank you very much. I actually ended up using fgets to check for EOF because everything else would just end up running the scan infinitely.